# how to parse postman-collection?

Tags: java, json, scala

**Goal**:

I am trying to parse the postman_echo collection json and persist the result into a new json copy  on disk, resulting the same file as the original one.

I prefer built-in data structure from the language,  but using json library should be good too. Not sure Antlr4 is a better way.

***follow-up question***
is it possible to allow any valid nested json in the body of post request?

update:
https://github.com/chakpongchung/postman-parser
In the end we come up with this satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A satisfactory solution is posted in the github link above in the question.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to what zoran mentioned is to create a case class if the structure is not too dynamic (with Play JSON). This would make it easier to compare the result.

```
case class MyObject(
  queryString: List[KeyValue],
  method: String,
  url: String,
  httpVersion: String
) ... and so on

object MyObject {
    implicit val format: Format[MyObject] = Json.format
}

case class KeyValue(name: String, value: String)

object KeyValue {
    implicit val format: Format[KeyValue] = Json.format
}
```

Then, you just need to do:

```
object JsonParser extends App {
  val postman_collections = "./scala_input.json"
  val jsonifiedString = scala.io.Source.fromFile(postman_collections).mkString

  val myJsonData = Try(Json.parse(jsonifiedString)).map(_.as[MyObject])

  myJsonData match {
    case Success(myValue) => // compare your case class here
    case Failure(err) => println("none")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. but what is it trying to do? 

both case class and object at the same time?

Also, the most tricky part is the part in `... and so on`. There is a nested json structure in the property `params`:

"
    "params": [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": "bar"
      },
      {
        "hello": {
          "test": "world"
        },
        "value": "bar"
      }
    ]
"

Comment: This approach can be accessed by key , but cannot be  written to disk with desired output

Comment: A satisfactory solution is posted in the github link above in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question well, but if you are trying to iterate over json string, you might try something like this:

```
  import play.api.libs.json.{JsObject, JsValue, Json}
  import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}


  object JsonParser extends App {
    val postman_coolections = "./resources/scala_input.json"
    val jsonifiedString = scala.io.Source.fromFile(postman_coolections).mkString

    val json: JsValue = Try(Json.parse(jsonifiedString)) match {
      case Success(js) => js
      case Failure(ex) => throw new Exception("Couldn't parse json", ex)
   }
 json.asInstanceOf[JsObject].fields.foreach{
   case (key: String, value: JsValue)=>
      println(s"Key:$key value:${value.toString}")
      writeFile(s"$key.json", Json.prettyPrint(value))
 }

//writing the whole postman input as a single file

writeFile("postmanInputFormatted.json", Json.prettyPrint(json))
writeFile("postmanInput.json", Json.stringify(json))

// To access individual property one option is to use this approach

val lookedValue = json \ "postData" \ "params" \ 1 \ "hello" \ "test"

lookedValue match {
  case JsDefined(value) => println(s"Test value is $value")
  case JsUndefined() => println("Didn't find test value")
}
// or
val lookedValueAlt = (json \ "postData" \ "params" \ 1 \ "hello" \ "test").getOrElse(throw SomeException)
```

Comment: It's not very clear from your comment what you are trying to achieve. I've updated my answer based on my understanding of your problem. You can't iterate json if you convert it to String, so you have to iterate JsValue, and convert it to String in order to persist it to the file either by using Json.prettyPrint or Json.stringify. Json.prettyPrint will keep json formating if you need that. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've update my answer to cover your first question how to access individual element if it exists. However, your question "I found JsValue type from Play Json will give undesired on-disk output" is not very clear. Could you please clarify what do you expect to get and what is actually your output? I'm getting correct output as given in input document.

Comment: A satisfactory solution is posted in the github link above in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your parser and most of them are that you are trying to use default parser to handle Json object as string. For example, in Request you are handling header as Seq[String] when it's actually Seq of (key, value) pairs. For this particular case, you should change it to something like this:

```
case class Request(
                method: String,
                header: Seq[HeaderItem], // header: []
                url: Option[Url] = None,
                description: String = ""
              )
object Request {
   implicit val format: Format[Request] = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format

case class HeaderItem(key: String, value: String)

object HeaderItem {
   implicit val format: Format[HeaderItem] = Json.format
 }
```

You can convert header to Seq[String] if you want, but you will have to write custom Read for that.
In the above case you also have cases when description is missing, so you want to handle that with default values.
You have such problems to handle in few other places as well, e.g. "response".

Another problem that I've noticed is a way how you handle "type" property from Json string. Type is reserved keyword, and you can handle it by wrapping it in ``, e.g.

```
case class Script(
    `type`: String,
     exec: Seq[String]
)
```

Comment: so it turns out that case class generator is not generating good case classes for this purpose? Still, after making this change, it is still not enough to parse the whole postman-json

Comment: Yes. As I wrote in the answer, this is not the only problem you have in your code. In case class Item1, you didn't properly parse response. You have to apply something similar as I did in this example for header. Response can't be "response: Seq[String]". It should be something like "response: Response", and then you would have "case class Response(name: String, originalRequest: OriginalRequest, status: String, code: Int, ...)" and so on. So, you need to provide proper mapping of all this.

Comment: If you just comment out line "response: Seq[String]"  from case class Item1, you will see that parser is working fine, which means the only outstanding problem is that response attribute.

Comment: I would advice that you take whole content of the response and generate case classes for it. Obviously case class generator you were using didn't properly generate it.